# How to make own wait function using async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to make a `wait` function that takes a time and waits for that time, but it is not working as I expect it to.

```js
var wait = async (t)=>{
    var c = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{setTimeout(()=>{resolve()},t)})
    await c
    console.log(2)
}
console.log(1)
wait(100)
console.log(3)
```

I know I can wait with plain `setTimeout()`, but I do not want to use that.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: `async` return promises. Unless everything inside them is synchronous (which `setTimeout` is not) they don't block. `await` can give the illusion of a promise being synchronous, which you should know since you are using it already, you're just not being it before `wait(100)`.

Comment: no its not because of that waits it inside `async` function

Comment: @MertÇelik — And while the function is waiting for the promise to resolve it goes to sleep and *the rest of the code runs*. (The rest of the code is not awaiting the promise)

Comment: @Quentin ok i understand why its not working but i didn't understand `what to do`

Comment: Like I said: `await wait(100)`

Comment: i know i can make it with doing it inside async function but how they making functions like `fs.readFileSync()`

Comment: just writing full script inside a anonymous async function solves the problem
`(async()=>{})()`